# C++ overflow of short type

Tags: c++, overflow, short

I experimented with following code [snipped](http://ideone.com/fTU6Je):

```
int main()
{
  short i = 0;
  do 
  {
    if (i + (short) 1 < (short) 0)
      std::cout << "MAX: " << i << std::endl;
    i++;
  } while (i > 0);
  std::cout << "MIN: " << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I expected that this code will output maximum and minimum value of `short` type. But it outputs just minimum value:

> MIN: -32768

I guess that comparison inside `for` loop calculates using `int` type. But I don't understand why compiler performs widening if all arguments has `short` type.

I tested it using MS Visual Studio 2013, x32 build.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: "why does the compiler widen arguments to int when they are all short?"  The answer is "because the standard says it must".  All arithmetic operations with signed operands that are actually narrower than `int` must be expanded to `int` first.  (Operands that are actually narrower than `int` may, depending on the implementation, be `char`, `short`, and `wchar_t`.)

The rules when some of the arguments are unsigned are more complex (and I can never remember them).

Aside: As others have noted, if you overflow a signed type the compiler can generate code which formats your hard disk.  Don't do it.  In particular, GCC is quite likely to spot that `i` starts at zero and is incremented so it will always be greater than zero and remove the test - so you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this detail about integer arithmetic. It's just an experiment and, of course, I wouldn't rely on such behavior.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of your code is undefined as eventually you'll overflow a `signed` integral type.

If you want to know the various limits of data types, then use, in your case

`std::numeric_limits<short>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<short>::max()` etc.

Don't ever rely on a signed counter "clocking" round from the maximum value to the minimum one.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the logic is such that it will only show a MIN. May be you need to change the comparison logic in your code to get both MAX and MIN.

ie..`if (i + (short) 1 > (short) 0)`

Also, don't forget to put a limit for the number of values else you will end up in an infinite loop